# Tour of chess king

Tags: directed-graphs, chessboard, knight-tours

Consider *lame* chess king that can move only one cell **left**, **down** and **diagonal upright**. Consider square chess board.

***Question:*** Can such a king visit all cells of a board (each cell only once) and end up in the cell to the left of the original?

I've tried many ideas: colorings, induction, graphs, etc. But nothing of these helped. Any help would be great!

Comment: did you try smaller boards?

Comment: Where does it start? And I am guessing it can’t visit the same square twice, right?

Comment: @Tan Yes, thank you, it can't, I'll fix it. It can start where you want.

Comment: @miracle173, yep, I haven't found such tours, but all mentioned ideas were banned!

Comment: Do you want the answer for a standard chess board ($8\times 8$) ?

Comment: It can't be done *(checked by brute force)*, for $n \times n, n\le 8$ grids.

Comment: Though, if you remove a corner, then $n\times n, n=3k, k\in\mathbb N$ grids work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can move and touch each square only once as shown in this picture. Start at the bottom right square

[image]

But we cannot end on the square left to the start square.

Such a tour consists of $l$ moves to the left, $d$ moves down and $x$ moves diagonal upright. The following equations hold:
$$l+d+x=63$$
because we touch every square of the $8\times 8$ squares exactly once.
$$d=x$$
because we end up in the same row as we started, so the number of down moves ($d$) must be equal to the number of up moves that can be only achieved by the diagonal moves($x$).
Finally the number of left moves($l$) must be one more than the number of right moves($x$), so
$$l=x+1$$

From this we get

$$(x+1)+x+x=63$$

which has no integer solution.

This argument works for all square boards because $n^2-2$ is not divisible by $3$ for any $n$.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you! I think it works for arbitrary square board, because length of tour will be N^2 - 1, which always is divisible by 3.

Comment: @Alexander for $N=3k$ the expression $N^2-1$ is not divisible by $3$. But $N^2-2$ is never divisible by $3$. I added this to my answer.